# "Самое важное" - какая часть речи слово "самое"?

Tags: морфология

Дано словосочетание: **самое важное**. Не **самое важное задание/дело** или ещё что-нибудь, а именно **самое важное**, где, как я пониаю, слово **важное** образовалось неморфологическим способом. Какой частью речи здесь является слово **самое**? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

*К первому ответу: дано словосочетание, в котором нужно определить части речи. Вы сказали, что "самое" - это определение, но мне нужно знать именно часть речи (местоимение, прилагательное и это что-то другое).

И нет, это не домашнее задание.*

Способ образования слова "важное" я отметил для того, чтобы акцентировать внимание именно на том, что это не прилагательное вроде "важное задание".

Это не домашнее задание, это - моё хобби. Я просто интересуюсь русским языком, делаю различные задания, чтобы закрепить изученное. Но не понимаю, почему меня активно игнорируют. Ведь я действительно не прошу ничего делать за меня - только проверить.

Comment: Вы в каком классе, простите? Спросите у преподавателя. Неужели откажет, если это просто хобби?

И нам так и скажите, делаю задания из такого-то учебника (хотя там обычно ответы есть), десять заданий сделал, десятой не понимаю. 

А так дело ж не в том, сами вы эти задания делаете или по указанию учительницы, это уж Бог вам судия. Этот контент **в принципе** не профильный для данного форума. Особенно, когда его становится много.

Answer (score 1):

Часть речи - определительное местоимение, член предложения - определение.
Некоторые лингвисты считают формообразующей частицей.

Comment: Тьфу, местоимение, конечно. Я про член предложения подумал... Убираю свой ответ.  
А вообще детям в школе дают такую штуку как "определительное местоимение"?

Comment: И в школе изучают, и на экзамене проверяют.